# Les mesures qui ont empêché

Tags: grammaire, accord

Found this sentence

> grâce aux mesures qui ont empêché ..

since the subject is in plural and feminine, shouldn't it be

> grâce aux mesures qui ont empêchées ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

le *participe passé* conjugué avec l’auxiliaire avoir s'accorde avec le complément d'objet si celui-ci est placé **avant**. En aucun cas il ne s'accorde avec le sujet.

La phrase correcte est bien :

> grâce aux mesures qui ont empêché ...

Un exemple avec accord :

> Les mesures ont empêché l'épidémie de s’aggraver.

---

> grâce aux mesures qui l'ont empêchée.

`l'` est le complément d'objet direct, placé avant ; le participe s'accorde.